# PHP date vs Ubuntu date mismatch

Tags: php

In ubuntu, `date` returns `Sat May 30 20:42:40 PDT 2015` and
`more /etc/timezone` returns `America/Los_Angeles`.

In PHP,`date_default_timezone_get()` returns `America/Los_Angeles`.

When I run `date("m/d/Y")` in PHP it returns `05/31/2015` -- why doesn't PHP match the system date?

Comment: What is the timezone setting in php.ini? Probably located at /etc/php.ini

Comment: I have `date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"` in php.ini

Comment: Good, matches `date_default_timezone_get()`. What does `date('c')` return in PHP?

Comment: Interesting, that returns `2015-05-30T21:02:06-07:00`.

Comment: It seems to be behaving as if you're running `date('m/t/Y')` and returning the days in the month, instead of the current day. What does `date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+ 5 days'))` produce?

Comment: `date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+ 5 days'))` produces `06/05/2015` while it's still May 30th on the system clock.

Comment: The only conclusion I can draw is that for some reason this system is rounding up. Perhaps generate a string with an hour as well, like `m/d/Y H`, then chop off the last three characters.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using an old version of PHP.

> date_default_timezone_set is for PHP 5.1.2 and above.

Try `php -v` and check your PHP version.

& also try

```
ini_set( 'date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles' );
```

instead of date_default_timezone_get()

Comment: @arby any updates ? upvote and accept the answer if helped thanks!